# How to retrieve spinner selected item after restarting app

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the selected items from the spinner after the restarting app. Here I have tried code to save the position of item but it's not working for me.

```
   @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefs.edit().putInt("spinner_indx", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).commit();


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(prefs!=null) {
        int spinnerIndx = prefs.getInt("spinner_indx", 0);
        spinner.setSelection(spinnerIndx);
    } }
```

Comment: onItemSelected you can store value and on restart check if there is any previous value stored or not if yes then add selection to that value

Comment: have you tried debugging your app to see wnat is wrong with it?

Comment: Actually I am trying to save selected spinner item of spinner in navigation drawer..its storing but there is error at setselection(spinnerIndx).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your on pause code to destroy method while closing the app it saves the dat and for on restart the OnResume() method first called then OnPause() method is getting called that's why you are not getting saved data

Comment: setselection is not working for spinner on navigationdrawer. I want to make selected item as first after restarting app.